# I want to create a scrollmap. Help me with logic

Tags: php, database, visualization, statistics

I am trying to make a quick visualization tool for getting info of a page , about where it is actually being scrolled based on cursor position of user. The final output will be somehthing like

!https://www.crazyegg.com/images/pricing/scrollmap.png

I am having a problem in the logic about how to get the data from user to keep it in database.
I did try, fetching cursor position for every instant and saving it in database, but the data to be stored would be huge.

What can be the possible solution for me to show the scrolling information according to time spent at a location ?

I am not asking for a piece of code actually , just the logic , that could be implemented here.

Thanks

Comment: javascript setTimeout + ajax requests.

Comment: Please ,Can you spend some words to explain how ?

Comment: Periodically send an AJAX request with infos about scroll and maybe mouse position to the server and store them in the database.

Comment: How about the region I have to take at each time ? Do you think I should look for duration of mouse cursor at each pixel position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the logic you established already sounds fine to me, it's just a question of intervals and meaningfulness of the data.

You are trying to collect data for a statistical analysis, the question is how much data does it take for your final result to make sense ? Is every nanosecond really that important ? Probably not, every 1/2 sounds better to me, of course that could vary depending on what results you get, so need to keep the interval easily changeable.

In the same way does it make sense to keep the precise pixel by pixel position ? Aren't the users going to move a bit when they stay on a area to look at pictures or read a text ? Probably, so you could simplify the position, not from a grid, but rather the difference between the current cursor position and the last recorded cursor position, if the difference is too big, then the user has changed area.

Or even better add the relative difference, if between 2 ticks the user move to the left 10 pixel, then you add to the total a negative difference, if at the tick after that he has moved 15px to the right, then add a positive difference, meaning the absolute total would be only a 5px move, not enough to say the user changed areas. Well of course you will need to keep 2 subtotals, one for horizontal moves and one for vertical ones and then determine if the user changed area with the two absolute subtotals, but you get the idea.

As for the meaningfulness of the data, do you need to keep all the moment of the user spent in a area without scrolling ? If not then just keep the last area and time spent there, and sent it to be recorded on the DB only when the user scroll.

Hopefully I was helpful and not confusing >_>

Comment: Really I was that spot on target on my first attempt ? Oh well ain't going to complain